# print date object as an object instead of the overwritten tostring method

Tags: javascript

How can I print in the console a Date as an object instead of a string?

I tryed the `Object.toString(MyDate);` command but this didn't work.

I need this because I extended my Date Object with prototype and want to see the object to look if it correct.

Comment: MyDate _is_ an object. However, it only exposes methods like `getDate()`, and not something like `MyDate.date`. If you want the latter you need to generate it yourself.

Comment: You can use [formatting pattern](http://v0.joehewitt.com/software/firebug/docs.php) `%o` in `console.log`: `console.log('%o', MyDate);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for `console.dir(MyDate);`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console.dir

```
Displays an interactive list of the properties of the specified JavaScript object.
The output is presented as a hierarchical listing with disclosure triangles that
let you see the contents of child objects.
```